# In Azure's Python service bus SDK, how do I query the shared access policies of a namespace?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python, azure-policy

I'm using Python 3.8 and Azure's service bus SDK (azure-servicebus==0.50.3).  Currently, I can use the below code to get a shared access policy rule (and key/value) for a specific topic within a namespace

```
from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient
...
    self._sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, subscription)
    ...
        rule = self._sb_client.topics.list_keys(
            self._resource_group_name,
            self._namespace,
            self._topic_name,
            SB_SAS_POLICY_LISTEN
        )
```

How do I make the logic a little more general so that I can query policies at the namespace level?  We have a root shared access policy and I wanted to see if there's a programmatic way to get the rule similar to the above.  I've tried excluding the topic parameter, but I'm unable it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha.  It appears you're specifically using `azure-mgmt-servicebus` for the tooling you're leveraging, which is exactly the right thing, and has the functionality you're looking for:

There is a comparable [list_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.namespacesoperations?view=azure-python#list-keys-resource-group-name--namespace-name--authorization-rule-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method present on the namespace as well as on a given topic, which would be called via `client.namespaces.list_keys(`.

Don't hesitate to shout if I've misunderstood or if any of this is unclear.